# Trying to create a new column which calculates % of total. eg: 'count_checked out' / 'Total'

Tags: sql, count, pivot

```
select
 Region
,HealthCenter_APPT
,APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM
,count(case when Appointment_Status in ('Checked Out','No Show') then APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM END) AS 'Total'
,count(CASE WHEN Appointment_Status like ('Checked Out') THEN APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM END) as 'Count_Checked_Out' 
**--,(count(CASE WHEN Appointment_Status like ('Checked Out') THEN APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM END)/count(case when Appointment_Status in ('Checked Out','No Show') then APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM END)) AS '%'**
,count (CASE WHEN Appointment_Status like ('No Show') THEN APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM END) as 'Count_No Show'
```

Comment: This query is missing a `from` clause and everything after it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use your query in sub-query and then do this operation as

```
Select Region
       ,HealthCenter_APPT
       ,APPOINTMENT_TYPE_TRIM
       , case when 'Total' <> 0 
              then 'Count_Checked_Out' * 100/ 'Total' 
         end as percentage_checkedout
       ...
  From (your_query_from_question) t
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `avg()`:

```
select  region, healthcenter_appt, appointment_type_trim,
    count(*) as total,
    sum(case when appointment_status = 'Checked Out' then 1 else 0 end) as count_checked_out
    sum(case when appointment_status = 'No Show'     then 1 else 0 end) as count_no_show
    avg(case when appointment_status = 'Checked Out' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_checked_out
from mytable
where appointment_status in ('Checked Out','No Show')
group by region, healthcenter_appt, appointment_type_trim
```

Note that I moved the filtering on the two statuses to the `where` clause, which simplifies the computation of the total count - but would filter out groups that have none of the two statues. If that's not what you want then:

```
select  region, healthcenter_appt, appointment_type_trim,
    sum(case when appointment_status in ('Checked Out', 'No Show') then 1 else 0 end) as total,
    sum(case when appointment_status = 'Checked Out' then 1 else 0 end) as count_checked_out
    sum(case when appointment_status = 'No Show'     then 1 else 0 end) as count_no_show
    avg(case 
        when appointment_status = 'Checked Out' then 1.0 
        when appointment_status = 'No Show'     then 0 
    end) as ratio_checked_out
from mytable
group by region, healthcenter_appt, appointment_type_trim
```